# Neo4j Cypher and nested WHERE condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Permission) 
WHERE NOT ((p)<-[:HAS|:CONTAINS*1..2]-(u:User) WHERE u.id = {userId}) AND p.minUserReputation <= {minUserReputation} 
RETURN p
```

I need to return all of the Permissions that are currently not assigned (`NOT ((p)<-[:HAS|:CONTAINS*1..2]-(u:User)`) to User(with `u.id = {userId}`) and filtered by min reputation value (`p.minUserReputation <= {minUserReputation}`)

Currently, this query fails with the following Cypher error:

```
Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Variable `u` not defined
```

Please help to fix this query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `WHERE <pattern>` and `WHERE EXISTS(<pattern>)` doesn't allow additional WHERE clauses on the pattern, it's best to match on the user first, allowing you to use your WHERE clause, then include the variable for that user in your predicate:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = {userId}
MATCH (p:Permission)
WHERE p.minUserReputation <= {minUserReputation} 
AND NOT (p)<-[:HAS|:CONTAINS*1..2]-(u) 
RETURN p
```